# Explanation about one of the hypotheses of Hôpital (Bernoulli) Theorem

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis

I'm studying Hôpital Theorem (even if historically the Theorem was formulated by Johann Bernoulli, but it's ok I guess), and one of the hypotheses reads:

- $f, g$ must be differentiable on $(a, b) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, and $g'(x) \neq 0, \forall x \in (a, b)$.

So here I am asking you: why do we need this condition?

When we are evaluating, for example, $\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1-\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$ we are evaluating the limit at a precise point.

According to the condition, we must build a "good interval" like $\left(a, \frac{\pi}{2}\right) \cup \left(\frac{\pi}{2}, b\right)$, but we have to pay attention because $g'(x) = -\sin(x)$ is zero at $\pi + k\pi$, for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$

In this way we cannot, say, use the interval $\left(-2\pi, \frac{\pi}{2}\right) \cup \left(\frac{\pi}{2}, 2\pi\right)$ because inside of it there are points like $\pi$.

So my question is again: why do we need this condition, since we are evaluating the limit at a precise point, and not "along" an interval?

Thank you!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27Hôpital%27s_rule#Derivative_of_denominator_is_zero

Comment: See [Stigler's law](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stigler%27s_law_of_eponymy).

Answer (score 1):

Recall the definition that the limit of $f$ at $a$ is $L$:
for all $\varepsilon>0$, there is $\delta>0$ such that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, if $0<|x-a|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$.
This can be reformulated as:
for any neighborhood $Y$ of $L$, there is some neighborhood $X$ of $a$
such that $f(X\setminus\{a\})\subseteq Y$.
As you can see, the very definition of limit at $a$ requires neighborhoods around $a$ (and in fact is irrelevant to the function value at $a$).
There really is nothing surprising if you need an interval around $a$ to deal with the limit at $a$.
Actually, if $a$ is an isolated point, then any real number can be a limit of any function at $a$.

Hopefully, this explains why "morally" we need such a condition in L'Hopital's rule.
As for why logically the condition $g'(x)\ne 0$ near $a$ is necessary.
You can refer to the example given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#Derivative_of_denominator_is_zero),
i.e. $f(x)=x+\sin(x)\cos(x)$ and $g(x)=f(x)e^{\sin(x)}$ as $x\to\infty$.
You can replace $x$ by $1/x$ so that you get the same counterexample as $x\to 0$.